# Externally hook into "tear down" of unit test in PHPUnit

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I've created a mock database class, which takes expected SQL queries as a parameter, and compares every call to it against that array of expected queries:

```
class Mock_Database
{
    public function __construct(PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase &$testcase, array $expected_queries);
    public function run_query($sql);
}
```

**The problem is** that I want it to automatically check if all queries have been run, when the test is finished. I'd like to have it automatically hook into the tearDown, or something similar. Is there a solution to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar issue. It's a bit unclean but, you can try to perform assertions after the test. "assertPostConditions" will be executed after each test case:

```
class Foo_Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /**
     * @see PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::assertPostConditions()
     */
    public function assertPostConditions()
    {
        $this->dbMock->verify();
    }
}
```

And throw an PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException — in the verify method — if something went wrong:

```
class Mock_Database {
    public function verify()
    {
        // detect differences and assign $allQueriesExecuted

        if (!$allQueriesExecuted) {
            throw new PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException(/*...*/);
        }
    }
}
```